# GitHub page build failure due to '{%' in code block

Tags: github, tags, markdown

On [my GitHub repo](https://github.com/aaronryank/Forked) I have this Markdown:

```
blah blah blah text

        v
        $
        |
    {%}-:-%&
```

Every time I have pushed with it, GitHub's page build fails because "the `{%` tag was not properly closed with `%}`". However, the `{%` is in a code block, so shouldn't it be ignored in ... whatever the page build is checking (I'm assuming it's Markdown)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Jekyll variable inside code blocks. Thus try the following:

```
{% raw %}
        v
        $
        |
    {%}-:-%&
{% endraw %}
```

Comment: "Apparently"?? Actually Jekyll runs the template system on the document before passing it to the Markdown parser. The template system knows nothing of Markdown syntax and has no way of knowing what is in a code block and what is not. Therefore, to avoid anything which resembles template syntax from being munged by the template system, you need to escape it.

Comment: @Waylan thanks for confirmation (I was just guessing ;))

Comment: Um, the `{% raw %}` and `{% endraw %}` are displayed in the rendered markdown. [link](https://github.com/aaronryank/Forked#examples-golfy)